Are all the variants of the following sentence correct?

He works with investors to understand their investment goals and find ways to maximize their profits.
He works with investors to understand their investment goals and to find ways to maximize their profits.
He works with investors to understand their investment goals and finds ways to maximize their profits.


Why do you think those all mean the same thing? They have different parses syntactically.

I don't think they mean the same thing, but I would like to know if any of them is grammatically incorrect.

Why do you think any of them are grammatically incorrect?

All 3 versions are grammatically correct.
1 and 2 have identical meaning and can be used interchangeably, 3 is subtly different.
In 1 & 2 "he works to find", which doesn't guarantee that he succeeds.
In 3 "he finds", which implies success every time.

Thank you so much for your input, @Peter Jennings.
